# Animations in Xamarin native project

Tags: animation, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

The question is a bit generic, but very simple :

Is it possible to do all the animations available in native apps (ios / android / wp) in a Xamarin native project (xamarin.ios, xamarin.android) ?

And is there any limitations?

Comment: There are not technically any limitations. You should be able to use a mixture of custom renderers, [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/), and the `DependencyService`, [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/), to access any and all native APIs. Having said that, I am sure that there are some that would be difficult to implement. You might get a more helpful answer by asking a specific question about one and posting the code that you have tried.

Comment: Thanks @hvaughan3, i have no specific code, i just need to decide between native and xamarin to develop a new project with many animations (flipbaord animations, tinder animations, etc...)

Comment: I understand the struggle. I would try and create a quick prototype of some of the animations if time allows (maybe choose the most difficult ones) to see if they will work in Xamarin Forms. Usually I would say that if you are already comfortable with coding in the native platforms and almost every page is going to have highly custom code, you may want to consider native, but Forms should technically allow everything.

Comment: thank you. unfortunately I did not have time to carry out a test project.
I just wonder if in "theory" everything is achievable with Xamarin.

Comment: In theory, it is achievable.